# Any way of condensing this ASP.net System.Net.Mail code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to send an email alert when a user log in fails.

Is there a simpler way of writing this so that the email routine doesn't have to be written out twice like this, for users that exist and users that do not exist? Essentially I am looking for a more efficient way of writing this.

Thanks for any help.

```
Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    LoginUser.FailureText = "Invalid Username or Password - Please Try Again"

    Dim UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

        If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Contact the system administrator"
        ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is disabled - Contact the system administrator"
        End If

        Dim Email_Error As New Thread(
            Sub()
                Dim mailObject As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                Dim emailCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "password")

                mailObject.To.Add("my@email.com")

                If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
                    mailObject.Subject = "User " & CurrentUser.ToString() & " is locked out"
                ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
                    mailObject.Subject = "User " & CurrentUser.ToString() & " is disabled"
                Else
                    mailObject.Subject = "User " & CurrentUser.ToString() & " login failed"
                End If

                mailObject.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("info@domain.com")
                mailObject.IsBodyHtml = True

                If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
                    mailObject.Body = "User is locked out"
                ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
                    mailObject.Body = "User is disabled"
                Else
                    mailObject.Body = "User login failed"
                End If

                Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.email.com")
                SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                SmtpMail.EnableSsl = False
                SmtpMail.Credentials = emailCredentials
                SmtpMail.Port = 587
                SmtpMail.Send(mailObject)
            End Sub
        )
        Email_Error.Start()

    Else
        Dim Email_NoUser_Error As New Thread(
            Sub()
                Dim mailObject As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
                Dim emailCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "password")

                mailObject.To.Add("my@email.com")

                mailObject.Subject = "Unknown User " & UserName.Text() & " login failed"

                mailObject.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("info@domain.com")
                mailObject.IsBodyHtml = True

                mailObject.Body = "Unknown User login failed"

                Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.email.com")
                SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
                SmtpMail.EnableSsl = False
                SmtpMail.Credentials = emailCredentials
                SmtpMail.Port = 587
                SmtpMail.Send(mailObject)
            End Sub
        )
        Email_NoUser_Error.Start()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The way the code is currently written actual creates and sends the e-mail on a different thread. Your best bet would be to move your mail sending code to another object.  Then you could just instantiate the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create the mailObject only once and set all the fields that stay the same, then call functions `Email_Error` and `Email_NoUser_Error` only to set those fields which vary, then after returning to the first function send it there.